# python try and except not giving expected values

Tags: python, try-except

Here is my python program

```
def try_ec(argument):
    try:
        int(argument)
    except:
        argument = input("Please enter a valid value: ")
a = []
score = 0
first = input("First Number: ")
try_ec(first)
first = int(first)
second = input("Second Number: ")
try_ec(second)
second = int(second)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTR7T.png)

I am trying to get an integer from the user and i am using try and except if the user enters a string by mistake. However my code is giving this error.
How do I make the code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you mutate a locale variable. First's value never changes.

Consider the following example

```
a = 5

def mut(arg):
  arg = 6

mut(a)
print(a) // 5
```

This is because arg is ia local copy of the argument that was passed in, it lives only in that functions scope.

And here is how we could do it,

```
a = 5

def mut(arg):
  arg = 6
  return arg


a = mut(a)
print(a) // 6
```

By returning the new computed value and assigned it to our initial variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must use while loop to check the process until it is correct.

For example:

```
def take_int_input(text):
    while True:
        argument = input(text)
        try:
            return int(argument)
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid value!")




first = take_int_input("First Number: ")
second = take_int_input("Second Number: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you might use recursion call method to convert it into `Int`.

```
   def try_ec(argument):
        try:
            return int(argument)
        except:
            inpt = input("Please enter a valid value: ")
            try_ec(inpt)


    a = []
    score = 0
    first = input("First Number: ")
    first = try_ec(first)
    second = input("Second Number: ")
    second = try_ec(second)
```